# How to group a string that has multiple words with awk? (Prints lines between 2 patterns)

Tags: awk, sed

I have an issue in which my string its not a single string; it is a string with multiple words; in which using sed works great; but not with awk;

How can I group all that string with awk? I tried to encapsulate the string with `" "`, with `{ }`, with `( )` and nothing works. Here is the example of my sed vs awk:

```
sed -n '/show system | inc Software/,/sh syst | i @@@@@/p' filename.txt > out_file.txt
```

That line works perfect with sed; the strings are `"show system | inc Software"` and `"sh syst | inc @@@@@"`

As for awk it doesnt work.

```
awk '/show system | inc Software/,/sh syst | i @@@@@/' filename.txt > out_file.txt
```

The output file is not what I expect. How can I do that strings to work in that command?

Comment: I think, by default `awk` will use extended regular expressions, so the patterns will match lines with either side of the `|`. You need to escape it as `\|` to match a regular bar.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that... Adding the escape "\" it makes it works.


- awk '/show system \| inc Software/,/sh syst \| i @@@@@/'   -> (works).  

- awk '/show system | inc Software/,/sh syst | i @@@@@/'    -> (doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

Your question will be easier to understand if you include your input data and expected output data.

The following `awk` command will print the lines 'show system | inc Software' and 'sh syst | i @@@@@' and every line in-between:

`awk '/show system \| inc Software/,/sh syst \| i @@@@@/{n=0}' filename.txt > out_file.txt`

Edit:

Also, it looks like your `sed` command won't work, (assuming I've understood your question) it should be:

`sed -n '/show system | inc Software/,/sh syst | i @@@@@/p' filename.txt > out_file.txt`

Comment: Hi Rusty. You are right; I forgot the -n flag at start and at the end it was /p flag and not /f. My bad..... it supposed to be -> sed -n '/show system | inc Software/,/sh syst | i @@@@@/p' filename.txt > out_file.txt

Comment: Your long awk command works exactly as this one I had but updated with the escape  -> awk '/show system \| inc Software/,/sh syst \| i @@@@@/'

Comment: @JavierGonzalez Oh yes, so it does. Answer updated.